# How do I get my tests to retry

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

I am currently looking at https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber-example and trying to get my tests to retry using the below line in package.json

`"test": "nightwatch --retries 5",`

In the docs there is a barrier symbol in support for retries, but no information about what this means. Am I missing something to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing it means there is a road block to implementing it. The red icons are mostly options that overlap with cucumber args so there is no point in implementing them. The retry functionality in Nightwatch was designed for the default test runner and doesn't work in Mocha or Cucumber. Best to raise an issue in the repo asking for clarification in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

ahaha))) you can use try-catch or switch-case-default with counter for that! it works!

```
async retryFunction() {
//do something
switch(e){
case firstCase:
//do_something;
break;
default:
await retryFunction();
}
}
```